# Get rows from a certain date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `table`

```
ID  |  date
=============
1   |  2024-12-13
2   |  2004-03-03
3   |  2011-07-13
4   |  2004-05-23
5   |  1996-08-05
```

Now I like to get the amount of entries older a certain date (timestamp) like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date > 1409072511
```

The `date` field is a "**longtext**" and cannot get changed!

Comment: I love when people say "the field can't be changed" or similar.  Why not?  You REALLY need to change that field or you will NOT be able to make an indexed query against that table. If you have to utilize date conversion functions on the stored field values you will not be able to use an index.

Comment: @MikeBrant cause other values are stored as well and users decide which content it have. Speed isn't the most important solution in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you need `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` conversion

see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d') > DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(1409072511))
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cf977/1)

AS ypercube mentioned in the comments it could be faster to do it this way all depends if you have indexes on your date field:

```
WHERE date > CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(1409072511) AS CHAR(10))
```

Comment: Yes he needs but first he needs `STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')` to convert date string to real date object

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid you are correct sorry I overlooked that

Comment: Even better: `WHERE date > CAST(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(1409072511)) AS CHAR)`

Comment: @ypercube someday i need to write a blog about which ways are faster or slower when dealing with dates.. aka converting to a date or casting the date to a string :) good advise though! i included your 2 cents in the answer giving credit where it is due :)

Comment: or: `CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(1409072511) AS CHAR(10))` If the column can be indexed, this will be able to use the index. The `STR_TO_DATE()` conversion will prohibit any index use.

Comment: @ypercube . . . You should answer the question so I can upvote your answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My comment was added in this answer.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks, the later is not required in my case cause the field is "longtext" and I can't add an index

Comment: @revaxarts You can index a text column with prefix (first 10 characters in your case.) But you should really consider using a `DATE` column instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can still convert the text to date using `STR_TO_DATE` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT
  id,
  `date`
FROM myTable
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')) > 1409072511
```

Or you could work directly with `DATE` usinng `STR_TO_DATE`.

Comment: downvoter care to explain?

Comment: +1 for doing it the opposite way from how I did it :)

Comment: This looks correct. Not index-friendly but correct.

Comment: @ypercube i tested it and it provides the correct result... not really sure who threw in a downvote on a working solution..

Comment: @ypercube I didn't actually knew that you could still use indexes in this situation using `CAST`, I ruled them out since the column was a text column, good to know.

Comment: @EndeNeu the trick is not related using CAST but to not using any function on the column. If the conversions (functions, CAST, etc) can be done only in the constant parameters, mysql is clever enough to do them only once (and not once for every row.) And even better, if there's an index, it might be used. And you are right, text columns are usually not indexed (perhaps because not all know that they can be prefix-indexed.)

Comment: Thanks for the calrification.